# Android WebView inside ScrollView VerticalFadingEdge fails alfa

Tags: android, android-webview, scrollview

Android 4.0

```
<ScrollView requiresFadingEdge>
<LinearLayout>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<WebView/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is working well if the web view doesn't fill the screen.  If it happens, the scrollView fading edge draws solid, leaving an empty top-bottom margin.  If I remove requiresFadingEdge, works well.

Does any body know any solution?  Thanks